# limit data usage of discord

Tags: networking, video-streaming, bandwidth

As far as my research took me, there is no way to set discord to manually reduce video quality. It can reduce it, but only if your bandwidth is poor. If your bandwidth is good, but the data plan is small, you get in trouble fast :P

So, the questions:

1. I'm I wrong? Can I limit the resolution of incoming videos to save bandwidth, regardless of what the user is sending?
2. Is there a way to limit the bandwidth available for a single app, so that discord will do me the favor and reduce the video feed quality?

(I am running ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Thanks! ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You can try installing and using Trickle (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/trickle.1.html). You should be able to limit bandwidth of Discord with this app.

Comment: I'll try it, thanks!